# screen flashes when I press ^S in gvim

Tags: vim, gvim

I bind ^S in gvim, by:

`map <C-S> :w<CR>`

Now if I press the <kbd>^S</kbd> combination, althrough file is saved (I saw the XXX written message), but gvim window flashes, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446320/in-vim-how-to-map-save-to-ctrl-s

Comment: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: @IngoKarkat `noremap <C-S> :w<CR>` still flashes